# столбцы из разных таблиц вывести в разные столбцы

Tags: sql

условно есть таблица 1, в ней есть `id`, `code` и `name`. в таблице 2 есть `id`, `code`, `name`.
вопрос вот в чём, как вывести `1.id` в один столбец и вывести `2.id` во второй столбец?
пробовал `join` правый, левый, внутренний и т.д.
подскажите, решение где то рядом, но ускользает от меня.

upd:

пробовал `cross join`, но он просто перемножил `id` из таблиц.

`left join` возвращает `id` только из таблицы 1.

`right join` возвращает `id` из таблицы 2, но почему-то пустые строки, но кол-во строк совпадает с кол-вом строк из 2 таблицы.

Comment: А что, таблицы как-то связаны?

Comment: @Oopss, id code name есть повторяющиеся значения, но не все

Comment: @Зонтик важнее было бы пример данных в табличках и ожидаемый результат. Попытки тут ни к чему

Comment: уточните вашу БД и какая связь между таблицами, именно логическую, а не на уровне сервера БД

Answer (score 0):

Уточните БД которое вы используете.
А вообще задача стандартная, попробуйте следующий запрос:
Насколько я понял, code является бизнес ключём, т.е. определяет уникальность записи..

Пусть это будут таблицы `Human` и `Enemy`:

```
SELECT H.Id, E.Id, 
  COALESCE(H.code, E.code) as code, 
  COALESCE(H.name, E.name) as name
FROM Human H
  FULL JOIN Enemy E on H.code = E.code
    --H.name = E.name -- это условие стоит раскомментировать, 
      --если связка по имени имеет место быть
```

Если это важно:

> @Oopss, id code name есть повторяющиеся значения, но не все

Можно добавить дистинкт в первую или вторую или в обе таблички перед соединением.

Получится что-то вроде:

```
SELECT H.Id, E.Id, 
  COALESCE(H.code, E.code) as code, 
  COALESCE(H.name, E.name) as name
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id, code, name FROM Human) as H
  FULL JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id, code, name FROM Enemy) 
    as E on H.code = E.code
```

Вам нужно определиться и описать в вопросе какая связь между этими таблицами. Я предположил, что поле `code`.